# Preferred swift style

Tags: swift

Which style is preferred? And which one is faster?

```
titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
```

vs

```
if let lbl = titleLabel? {
    lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    lbl.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2 
}
```

Comment: As always, if you're worried about speed, us a profiler. It's too dependent on too many things for a canonical answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Worry about readability, not speed.

Notice that if you drag in Xcode to create the outlets, it will create them with ! (forced unwrapping) rather than ?. It's expected at runtime that the outlets will be properly connected, so you shouldn't have to check. Your IBOutlets should look like this:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
```

Your code for manipulating IBOutlet objects should generally look like this:

```
self.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
self.titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center
self.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
```

On the other hand, if you're conditionally creating this view in code (nil is a valid value)...

```
private var titleLabel: UILabel?
```

If you're going to create the view and set its values together:

```
let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(...))
titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center
titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
self.titleLabel = titleLabel
```

If you've created the view elsewhere (so it's optional), and now you need to update its properties:

```
if let titleLabel = self.titleLabel {
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
}
```